# Python JSON writing without backslashes

Tags: python, json, dictionary, backslash

- List item

I have a 'quad' folder with 2 files (oracle_1.sql and oracle_2.sql)
and a 'config' folder with the 'config.json' file.

My code is below:

```
import os, json
quadversion = ("develop-62")
x = os.listdir("quad/")
i=0
listscripts = []

while (len(x)) > i:
    script = ('{"ignoreErrors": False, "script": "quad/lma/dba-tests/'+(quadversion)+'/scripts/'+(x[i])+'"}')
    i+=1
    listscripts.append(script)

with open('config/config.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    tmp = data['containers']['runtimeEnvironment']['data']['properties']['sqlScripts']['value']
    data['containers']['runtimeEnvironment']['data']['properties']['sqlScripts']['value'] = listscripts

    f.seek(0)
    f.write(json.dumps(data, indent = 4, sort_keys=True))
    f.truncate()
```

It's returning backslashes on JSON file - key called "value":

```
{
    "containers": {
        "runtimeEnvironment": {
            "data": {
                "properties": {
                    "sqlScripts": {
                        "type": "SqlScripts",
                        "value": [
                            "{\"ignoreErrors\": False, \"script\": \"quad/lma/dba-tests/develop-62/scripts/oracle_1.sql\"}",
                            "{\"ignoreErrors\": False, \"script\": \"quad/lma/dba-tests/develop-62/scripts/oracle_2.sql\"}"
                        ]
                    }
```

And the result could be this on key called "value":

```
"value": [
          {"ignoreErrors": False, "script": "quad/lma/dba-tests/develop-62/scripts/oracle_1.sql"},
          {"ignoreErrors": False, "script": "quad/lma/dba-tests/develop-62/scripts/oracle_2.sql"}
         ]
```

Comment: You've got a list of strings, not of dictionaries (which would be serialised as objects).

Comment: replace `script = ('{"ignoreErrors": False, "script": "quad/lma/dba-tests/'+(quadversion)+'/scripts/'+(x[i])+'"}')` with `script = ({"ignoreErrors": False, "script": "quad/lma/dba-tests/'+(quadversion)+'/scripts/'+(x[i])+'"})` and it should be okay

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is your `listscript` variable is a list of `strings` instead of a list of dictionaries.
Your `script` has to be a dictionary:

```
while (len(x)) > i:
    script = {"ignoreErrors": False, "script": "quad/lma/dba-tests/" + quadversion + "/scripts/" + x[i]}
    i+=1
    listscripts.append(script)
```

Comment: Upvoted, but do fix your quotes :) You edited just half of his line, or something.

Comment: Indeed, I fixed it :)